# Resolve a hostname and know where the answer came from?

Tags: dns, nsswitch

As part of auditing a RANCID server, I would like to be able to figure out whether it's resolving a particular hostname via /etc/hosts, DNS or some other source. Is there a generic (without me hardcoding the logic and order of my particular `nsswitch.conf`) way to do this?

gethostbyname just gives me the result. Do does getent, as far as I can tell, although I can get it to only use file or dns with the `-s` option, that still means I am parsing nsswitch.conf to decide which one it would have chosen, or assuming the configuration.

Comment: Systemd-resolved provides an API over dbus, which returns this information as a bit set in a bitmap. I don't know if this helps you or not. See https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved/

Comment: Well, sort of... it looks like it would do the trick. Now I just need to figure out how dbus works :-)